# How to pass an HtmlString as a Func<dynamic, HelperResult>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using Phil Haack's [RenderSection helper](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/05/defining-default-content-for-a-razor-layout-section.aspx) to define layout Sections with default content.  It all works nicely but in one case the default content is contained in an HtmlString.  I had to wrap the variable expression in a span like this:

```
@this.RenderSection("aSectionName", 
   @<span>@anHtmlStringVariable</span> 
)
```

to get the Razor engine to interpret the HtmlString correctly. While it is unlikely that adding a span is going to cause problems for my layout it seems like I shouldn't have to wrap it like that.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: I'm not able to test, but does `<text>@anHtmlStringVariable</text>` work?

Comment: Ah you are right sir.  I completely assumed that this would have emitted the literal string "@anHtmlStringVariable".  I should have checked in spite of my assumptions.  I encourage you to submit that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<text>@anHtmlStringVariable</text>`.